# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.1.0

Tags: java, wso2, esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I get following error when running WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.1.0 from the Integration studio on Ubuntu 22.04 .

```
 ERROR {NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaught exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should analyze the heap dump and try to figure out why the OOM issue happened. If the OOM happened due to insufficient allocation of memory to the applications, you can follow the below steps to increase memory allocation.

If the OOM happened in the Micro Integrator runtime you can try increasing the memory allocation for the JVM by referring [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/performance_tuning/tuning_jvm_performance/). If it was the Integration Studio you can increase the memory allocation by increasing the memory in `INTEGRATION_STUDIO_HOME/IntegrationStudio.ini`.

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the JVM values as below.

1. In the Integration Studio, click the top level menu **Run** and go to **Run Configurations**.
2. Click on the **Arguments** section on the Micro Integrator server.
3. You can increase **Xms** and **Xmx** values under **VM arguments**.

[image]